# Angular 6 Reactive Form Input Value to UpperCase

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Reactive form in Angular 6. For input type text I want it to be uppercase. I tried the solution

```
(input)="form.patchValue({name: $event.target.value.toUpperCase()})"
```

The solution works fine, but the only problem when I move cursor to middle and type a character, the cursor moves at the end.

Is there any other approach or any better solution?

Answer (score 11):

You can try this:

```
const yourControl = this.form.get('yourControlName');
yourControl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  yourControl.patchValue(yourControl.value.toUpperCase(), {emitEvent: false});
});
```

Answer (score 10):

why don't you just use CSS to do the job?

```css
.uppercase{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<input class="uppercase" type="text" placeholder="type here">
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but model value is still in lowercase.

Comment: in that case, you can use (change) event instead of (input) with style text-transform: uppercase to visually see the uppercase in the input view. when the input field will lose focus then the model will be uppercase.
I reproduced the problem here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zitpkn

Comment: Good suggestion for the UI - I already had a (change) event so this was useful as I can to toUpperCase() in my change event and let this handle the UI transform.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is reeeeally late, but...

You could hook on to the (change) event instead of the (input) event.  Your case changes won't execute until after the user leaves the field, but it will prevent the cursor from jumping.

You case changes will still execute if the user submits the form by pressing Enter while in the field.